# Dudas En Python - Parametros de usuario en query - Asignador en python

Tags: python, django

Amigos de Stackoverflow soy un desarrollador empirico en python y estoy haciendo una aplicacion donde hay un Administrador y varios usuarios operarios, el Administrador asigna cierta cantidad de registros a el operario, este los ve en un listado y selecciona uno de ellos, y modifica la informacion yal final vuelve y guarda todo a la base

tengo dos problemas, el primero es en el views.py cuando hago el query como hago para que tome el dato de a que usuario esta asignado y solo muestre los del usuario autenticado. 
este es mi

## Views.py

```
def asignacion(request):
conteo_asig = Cuenta.objects.all().filter(ESTADO_INTERNO='ASIGNADO').count()
conteo_liq = Cuenta.objects.all().filter(ESTADO_INTERNO='LIQUIDADO').count()
conteo_rea = 
Cuenta.objects.all().filter(ESTADO_INTERNO='REASIGNADO').count()
conteo_hoy = Cuenta.objects.all().filter(
  FECHAR_LIQUIDA__gte=datetime.date.today()).count()
cuenta = Cuenta.objects.all().filter(ESTADO_INTERNO='ASIGNADO')
contexto = {'cuentas': cuenta, 'title': 'Mis Cuentas', 'asigna_count': conteo_asig,
  'liquida_count': conteo_liq, 'reasigna_count': conteo_rea, 'hoy_count': conteo_hoy}
assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
return render(request, 'liquidacion/asignacion.html', contexto)
```

asi es como llamo la asignacion de cada operario

## asignacion.html

```
{% extends "liquidacion/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}


 <div class="py-5" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="">Mis Cuentas</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="">Aqui podra usted consultar, re liquidar y organizar las cuentas que han pasado por su usuario. </p>
       <ul class="col-md-4 list-group "  >
        <li class="list-group-item text-center d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center inline"> Cuentas Realizadas Hoy
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ hoy_count }} </span></ul>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="list-group" >
          <a href="{% url 'asignacion' %}">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> Cuentas Asignadas
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ asigna_count }} </span>
        </li></a>
        <a href="{% url 'reasignada' %}">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> Cuentas Re Asignadas
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ reasigna_count }}</span>
        </li></a>
       <a href="{% url 'liquidada' %}">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> Cuentas Liquidadas
          <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ liquida_count }}</span>
        </li></a>
      </ul>            

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br></br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
           {% if cuentas %}

    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead class="card-header" >
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>NINID</th>
            <th>Radicado</th>
            <th>Factura</th>
            <th>Prestador</th>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Servicio</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Tipo Recobro</th>
            <th>Accion</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


          {% for cuenta in cuentas %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{cuenta.id}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_ID}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_NRORADICA}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_NROFACT}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_NOM_IPS}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_AFI_IDENTIFIC}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_MAPIISS_DESCRIPCION}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_VALOR_NOPOS}}</td>
            <td>{{cuenta.NIN_TIPANEXO_AUTORIZACION}}</td>
            <td> <a href="{% url 'liquidacuenta' cuenta.id  cuenta.NIN_NRORADICA %}">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>Ir </a></td>
          </tr> 
          {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
         </table>
   </div>
         {% else %}
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead class="card-header" >
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>NINID</th>
            <th>Radicado</th>
            <th>Factura</th>
            <th>Prestador</th>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Servicio</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Tipo Recobro</th>
            <th>Accion</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>





        </tbody>

      </table>

      {% endif %}


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

## Urls.py Aplicacion

```
path('asignacion/', views.asignacion, name='asignacion'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener todos los registros de un usuario autenticado puedes intentar hacer como lo siguiente:

```
cuenta = Cuenta.objects.filter(<id_usuario>=request.user.pk, ESTADO_INTERNO='ASIGNADO')
```

> En donde "id_usuario" es el nombre del campo id de tu tabla de usuarios y request.user.pk, es el ID del usuario que este logeado.

Comment: Perfecto Amigo Funciono correcto, pero me gustaria saber como seria la vista de el administrador para asignar X cantidad de registros a esa pk de cada usuario

Comment: A que te refieres exactamente, a la logica?, es un poco amplia tu pregunta.